# Duplicate array

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, duplicates

I need to duplicate and manipulate an array variable, but for some reason when I push a value into the newly created array it is pushing the value into the original array.

```
function testing (point) {
    var newArray = currentChain;
    newArray.push(point);
}
```

In this situation, point is being added to the `currentChain` variable.
Note that nowhere am I setting `currentChain` equal to `newArray` and there are no other variables in the script called `newArray`. Why would it be behaving this way?

Comment: Javascript (like Java and many other languages) uses [call-by-sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing) for objects, so `newArray` and `currentChain` point to the same array object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this you need to clone your array. For example by using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method:

```
var newArray = currentChain.slice();
```

This happens because your `newArray` is a pointer to `currentChain` Array.

Answer (score 1):

Because both `newArray` and `currentChain` share the same reference, so changing one affects the other too.

Use `newArray = []` to avoid this, since your naming of the array means so.

Comment: "Note that no where am I setting currentChain equal to newArray" ;-)